Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'admin - with - ajax_url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
This has been driving me crazy. I've been trying to make an ajax call via php thats connected to frontend javascript on wordpress.
Here's the javascript:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const skincareKitBuilder = {
            ajax_url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('skincare_kit_builder_nonce'); ?>'
        };


Do i Need to just ditch the frontend js and make a js file and upload it with the php as a plugin or is there a syntax or permissions/file location error going on here?
I tried this in the php file thinking it would work but didnt do a thing if parsing was the issue...
// Register and enqueue the scripts and styles for the frontend
function skincare_kit_builder_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('skincare-kit-builder-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/skincare-kit-builder.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('skincare-kit-builder-js', 'skincareKitBuilder', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('skincare_kit_builder_nonce')
    ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'skincare_kit_builder_enqueue_scripts');


On which line, of which file exactly, does it say the syntax error occurred? You've only posted part of the error message.

sorry, in the javascript within the onpage code editor on this line (581) - ajax_url: '',

I'm guessing that JS code is in a .js file. PHP won't operate on that file
